# Create digest auth header

Tags: java, digest-authentication

I want to create a header in order to get a resource from a web service which is protected by a digest auth, I have the login and password but I did not find the right way to create this header like postman.

Comment: any solution about this issue, I tried to create a header with authorization key but it did not work

Comment: Can you give more elaboration on 'header like postman' part ?

Comment: If you're talking about [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication), you should have a realm and a nonce too. Is it the case?

Answer (score 0):

There're two key points, one is calculate the auth key, the other is pass key in request header. Depending on the service authentication method, you can read documentation of the service to do the calculation. I focus on later part, that you can pass the key in header like below:

```
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.HttpClient;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpClients;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.ContentType;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.io.entity.StringEntity;

public void post() throws IOException {
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    String url = "http://127.0.0.1:5050/vaccine/report";
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    post.addHeader("x-auth-token", "computed value");
    String body = "{\n" +
            "    \"siteId\":3,\n" +
            "    \"injectCount\":3,\n" +
            "    \"email\":\"yanghe@xyz.com\"\n" +
            "}";
    HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(body, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    post.setEntity(entity);

    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);

    System.out.println("response code: "+ response.getCode());

    
}

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents.client5/httpclient5 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

No example like the [source example](https://www.codingninjas.com/codestudio/library/authorization-types-in-postman-including-no-auth-basic-auth-digest-auth-bearer-token-oauth). If you want to use request headers:

1. Select the API Key option from the list in the request Authorization tab
2. Enter your key in the dialogue box in front of “Key.”
3. Enter the value corresponding to your key in the dialogue box in front of “value.”
4. Select between Header and Query params from the list.

[image]

This is what the `Postman` team are saying:

> "This method of authorization is a little more complex than the
> methods mentioned above. In this method, the server sends some details
> when a client sends the first request to the API. During this time,
> the server generates an encrypted string using this passed data and
> stores it for future purposes. This data contains a “nonce” field ( a
> number that you can use only one time), other few details, and a 401
> unauthorized response.
>
> After receiving these details from the server, send an array of
> data(encrypted), which also contains username and password and the
> data that the server sent you in the first place.
>
> When you send the second request, the server matches the stored
> encrypted string with the data you sent in your request and decides
> whether to authenticate you.   Select Digest Auth from the dropdown
> list in the Authorization section of a request to use this method."

And they provide exactly how to enter a digest request on Postman:

[image]